# Create a stack that holds doubles in cpp

Tags: c++

In the book "thinking in C++" there is an exercise problem asking to create a stack that holds doubles, and fill with 25 double values and then print them out to the console. My codes for this problem is as follows:

**Stack.h**

```
//Stack.h
struct Stack {
struct Link {
    void* data;
    Link* next;

    void initialize(void* dat, Link* nxt);
}* head;

void init();
void push(void* element);
void* pop();
void cleanup();
};
```

**StackLib.cpp**

```
#include "Stack.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void Stack::init()
{
    head = 0;
}

void Stack::Link::initialize(void* dat, Link* nxt)
{
    data = dat;
    next = nxt;
}

void Stack::push(void* element)
{
    Link* newLink = new Link;
    newLink->initialize(element, head);
    head = newLink;
}

void* Stack::pop()
{
    if (head == 0) return 0;

    void* vp = head->data;
    Link* oldhead = head;
    head = head->next;
    delete oldhead;
    return vp;
}   

void Stack::cleanup()
{
    cout << "Clean up the Stack!" << endl;

    Link* tmpLink;
    while(head != 0){
        tmpLink = head->next;
        delete head;
        head = tmpLink;
    }
}
```

**Test.cpp**

```
#include "Stack.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    Stack dbStack;
    dbStack.init();

    int i;
    double d;


    for(i = 0; i < 25; i++){
        d = i/10.0;
        dbStack.push(&d);
    }

    for(i = 0; i < 25; i++)
        cout << *(double *)dbStack.pop() << endl;
}
```

When I execute the program, the output are

```
2.4
2.4
2.4
2.4
(output omitted)
```

All of them are 2.4, which is not what I expect! So what's wrong with my code?

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. In general, don't tag both.

Comment: Hi.  Asking people to spot errors in your code is not especially productive. You should use the debugger (or add print statements) to isolate the problem, by tracing the progress of your program, and comparing it to what you expect to happen. As soon as the two diverge, then you've found your problem. (And then if necessary, you should construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org).)

Comment: If you're using C++, use _constructors_ instead of an `.init` function. If your book doesn't mention constructors or advises `.init` functions, get a good book. SO has a good C++ book list.

Comment: Totally agree to Oli. Just try to trace contents of your stack after it is populated. It might give you a hint.

Comment: Try and use the debugger, it can help you a lot. Never leave a problem "somewhere in my program", try to isolate it to few lines of code.

Comment: Defining an iterators (`i`) outside a `for` loop is not very C++.

Comment: Using `void*` and not template class for a stack is not very C++-style.

Comment: If the stack is going to hold doubles, why don't you give `Link` a `double` field instead of a `void*`?

Comment: You're pushing 25 pointers to the same variable `d` in the above code. Create a new `double`s and `push` them onto the stack (also don't forget to delete it when you `pop` them out).

Comment: If it's a stack of doubles, why is it storing pointers to void? That's *not" how you think in C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the first glance, the problem might be this line:

```
dbStack.push(&d);
```

You're pushing the value by it's reference, which means, that all the values in your stack will be the same as the last value held by the variable `d`

Comment: Yes, this is the problem! I altered my code by creating an array to hold the doubles, and push them by `dbStack.push(d+i)`, and the output became what I want. Thx a lot!

Answer (score -3):

This isn't the answer you're looking for, but as a commenter said:

**Step through your code.**

That's what I was about to do for you, then I remembered: teach a man to fish...

If you're not using an IDE (*but you should be*), you can add print statements to show the changing values of variables as the program progresses.

Comment: If it is not an answer don't post it as such please.

Comment: It *is* an answer, just not what he's expecting.

Comment: While I agree with you, there are certain rules at SO. Answers should answer and advices.

Comment: He does not need to use an IDE. You can even debug in a console....